# Как растянуть меню на полную ширину блока?

Tags: html, css

Например, если изменить название "Человеки" на "Люди", то меню перестает быть на полную ширину блока.

```
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-menu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Новини</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Человеки</a></li>
            <li><div><a href="#">Треки</a>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li ><a href="#">Альбоми</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Free Download</a></li>
                    <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Радио шоу</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Лейбли</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Популярне</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.menu {

    display: table;
}

ul.menu {
    border: none;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
}

ul {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.content-menu > ul > li{
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;   
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 -1px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    padding: 1px;
    position: relative;
}

.content-menu a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 13px 31px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
}

.content-menu ul {
    line-height: 20px;
}

.content-menu li ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.content-menu li ul:hover {
    display: block;
}

.content-menu ul li.first {
    border-top: 0 none;
}

.content-menu ul li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 0 none;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.content-menu ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.content-menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

.content-menu li > ul:hover {
    display: block;
}

li.leaf {
   padding: 0.2em 0.5em 0 0;
   margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
   display: block;
   float: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
   border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}

.content-menu > ul > li:hover {
   border: 2px solid #1A1A1A;
   padding: 0px;
   z-index: 1002;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скажу честно - обломался я корректировать весь ваш css, т.к. глядя на всё это, руки опускаются. [Смотрите такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Sn8xL/1/). Возможно, это то, что вы хотели.